# Time complexity to check if a key exists in an object using "in" property

Tags: javascript

What is the time complexity to check if a key exists in an object using `in` property:

Example:

```
var obj = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    ...
}

if("key1" in obj)
```

Comment: average O(1), it's a hashmap. Only issues you will have is when being under hash-collision attacks, which isn't your daily situation, unless working on core routines of finance handling code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the [V8 Design docs](https://v8.dev/)

> Most JavaScript engines use a dictionary-like data structure as
> storage for object properties - each property access requires a
> dynamic lookup to resolve the property's location in memory. This
> approach makes accessing properties in JavaScript typically much
> slower than accessing instance variables in programming languages like
> Java and Smalltalk. In these languages, instance variables are located
> at fixed offsets determined by the compiler due to the fixed object
> layout defined by the object's class. Access is simply a matter of a
> memory load or store, often requiring only a single instruction.
>
> To reduce the time required to access JavaScript properties, V8 does
> not use dynamic lookup to access properties. Instead, V8 dynamically
> creates hidden classes behind the scenes. [...] In V8, an object
> changes its hidden class when a new property is added.

so basically it would be O(1) in time complexity to check for a key in an object even if the JavaScript engines use a dictionary-like data structure because on average accessing a key in a dictionary would be O(1).